# Jquery UI Download : which files to include?

Tags: jquery-ui

I understand that color animations are not natively supported by Jquery. So i have downloaded the Jquery UI zip.
Which files inside the zip should i add below the jquery script to support color animations?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What the hack is too broad about this question O.o? It is pretty specific, even if it was a really general question "which files to include from jQuery UI download" .... Altought the title could be appended by " for jQuery UI to work" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get jQuery UI up and running, you should add `jquery-ui.min.js` under the jQuery script, and `jquery-ui.min.css` to your document's head.

The ".min" means that the JavaScript and CSS is minified so it's more space-efficient for production use. If you want to be able to debug the jQuery UI code, use the non-minified versions.

More details:
https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/

Comment: my animations still dont seem to work :/

Comment: @RimilDey For further help, please reproduce the problem using a [minimal, complete, and verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i was making a silly syntax error. Thanks maximillian! :)